# What is the best way to expose methods from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, module

Consider I want to expose a method called `Print`

1. Binding method as `prototype`:

File Saved as Printer.js

```
var printerObj = function(isPrinted) {
            this.printed = isPrinted;        
    }

printerObj.prototype.printNow = function(printData) {
        console.log('= Print Started =');
};
module.exports = printerObj;
```

Then access `printNow()` by putting code `require('Printer.js').printNow()` in any external .js node program file.

1. Export method itself using `module.exports`:

File Saved as Printer2.js

```
var printed = false;   
function printNow() {
console.log('= Print Started =');
}    
module.exports.printNow = printNow;
```

Then access `printNow()` by putting code `require('Printer2.js').printNow()` in any external .js node program file.

Can anyone tell what is the difference and best way of doing it with respect to Node.js?

Comment: 'Expose' in what way?   As a web app?  Or are you asking about CommonJS conventions?

Comment: @7zark7 As a module for my Node.js web app..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely the first way. It is called the `substack pattern` and you can read about it on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/n8agrin/status/261151288685907968) and on Mikeal Rogers' [blog](http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/coffee-perspective.html). Some code examples can be found at the [jade github repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/parser.js) in the parser:

```
var Parser = exports = module.exports = function Parser(str, filename, options){
  this.input = str;
  this.lexer = new Lexer(str, options);
  ...
};

Parser.prototype = {

  context: function(parser){
    if (parser) {
      this.contexts.push(parser);
    } else {
      return this.contexts.pop();
    }
  },

  advance: function(){
    return this.lexer.advance();
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 for the substack pattern reference and link. Although I think Amol is using this pattern in both examples since he only returns a single function in either case, right?

Comment: yeah, that's right! As addition to your answer Arnol should use lowercase variables when he isn't writing constructor functions. Otherwise good explanation!

Comment: @zeMirco as per you suggestion variables are now in camel case. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you are creating a class, ideally you should use it with "new" in your caller program:

```
var PrinterObj = require('Printer.js').PrinterObj;
var printer = new PrinterObj();
printer.PrintNow();
```

This is a good read on the subject: http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/js-inheritance-by-example.html

In the second example you are returning a function.

The difference is that you can have multiple instances of the first example (provided you use new as indicated) but only one instance of the second approach.